# Sorting an array in a decreasing order in Java

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm trying to code a program that will sort the given strings one by one first and then sorting all the strings both in decreasing order I managed to sort the string character by character but I am having trouble in sorting all the sorted (character by character) strings. I tried using the Array.sort() but it does not sort it decreasingly and it only sorts the first input not the already sorted array

```
    package com.company;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    static void sortString(String str)
    {
        char[] chArr = str.toCharArray();
        String SortString = "";
        for (int i = 0; i< chArr.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j< chArr.length; j++)
            {
                if(chArr[i] > chArr[j])
                {
                    char temp = chArr[i];
                    chArr[i] = chArr[j];
                    chArr[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        String[] SortedString = new String[5];

        for (int k = 0; k<chArr.length;k++)
        {
            SortString = SortString + chArr[k];
        }
        Arrays.sort(SortedString);
        for (int counter = 0; counter<5; counter++)
        {
            System.out.println(SortedString[counter]);
        }


    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner UserInput = new Scanner (System.in);

        String[] names = new String[5];

        for (int counter = 0; counter<5; counter++)
        {
            do
            {
                System.out.print("Input String #" + (counter+1) + ": ") ;
                names[counter] = UserInput.next().toLowerCase();
            }while(names[counter].length() > 25);

        }
        UserInput.close();
        Arrays.sort(names);
        for (int counter = 0; counter<5; counter++)
        {
            sortString(names[counter]);
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Did you try using Collections.reverseOrder()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static String sortString(String str)
{
    char[] chArr = str.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i< chArr.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j< chArr.length; j++)
        {
            if(chArr[i] > chArr[j])
            {
                char temp = chArr[i];
                chArr[i] = chArr[j];
                chArr[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return new String(chArr);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner UserInput = new Scanner (System.in);

    String[] names = new String[5];

    for (int counter = 0; counter<5; counter++)
    {
        do
        {
            System.out.print("Input String #" + (counter+1) + ": ") ;
            names[counter] = UserInput.next().toLowerCase();
        }while(names[counter].length() > 25);

    }
    UserInput.close();
    // Arrays.sort(names);   No point sorting here
    
    String[] strings = new String[5];
    for (int counter = 0; counter<5; counter++)
    {
        strings[counter] = sortString(names[counter]);
    }

     Arrays.sort(strings);

      // increasing order:
     for(String s : strings) {
         System.out.println(s);
     }
     
     // decreasing order:        
     for(int i = 4; i >= 0; i--) {
         System.out.println(strings[i]);
     }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for your answer I tried to compile it but it is not Sorting each individual string anymore

Comment: It will if you paste into your Main class.

Comment: Input: Input Inputz  Java  Javax Python Output:pthony inptuz inptu ajavx ajav Expected Output: zutpni xvjaa ytponh vjaa utpni

Comment: NeverMind I got it by using the last part of your code THANKYOU SO MUCH YOU ARE A LIFE SAVER

Comment: Please add some explanations. Just dropping code only answers isn't a good thing. People learn by understanding, and that works much better with context information.